# Translation help

Tags: english-to-japanese

I’m trying to say “asking One’s annual income sounds like you are trying to boast.” Would 「 年収を聞いたら、「大口な目的があるでしょう」と思います 」be right?

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem with your sentence:

> 年収{ねんしゅう}を聞{き}いたら、「大口{おおくち}な目的{もくてき}があるでしょう」と思{おも}います。

is none other than the fact that the middle part 「大口な目的があるでしょう」 makes practically no sense.  The only thing it could possibly mean to native speakers would be "***(Someone) would have a big purpose***.", which is not  what you want to express this time.

The word 「大口」 ***cannot mean "brag" or "boast" all by itself***.  To mean that, it needs to be used with the verb 「たたく」 as in 「大口をたたく」.  For this reason, 「大口な目的」 sounds pretty much non-sensical.

Even so, 「大口をたたく」 is not the phrase you would need to use in your sentence this time.  I would use 「自慢{じまん}」 and say:

> 「人{ひと}の年収を聞くと、自分{じぶん}の年収を自慢したがっているように思{おも}われてしまうこと（が/も）あります。」

Answer (score 2):

大口な目的がある (literally "have a big mouth purpose (?)") makes very little sense to me. [大口](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%A4%A7%E5%8F%A3) usually refers to something unrealistically grandiose and big (like "I'll be the world champion in a year" said by a rookie), and it's almost always used in an idiom [大口を叩く](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/288610/meaning/m0u/). In this case, you can use 自慢する instead.

> 年収を聞いたら、「自慢している」と思います。

But this sentence is still very hard to understand, because you have omitted the person pronouns too much. The subject of the sentence switched suddenly in the last half of the sentence; the person who *asked* (聞く) is not the person who *thought* (思う) "you're boasting!"

Use a consistent subject, and also clarify whose income you're talking about:

> **人の**年収を聞いたら、**自分の**年収を自慢していると**思われ**ます。

Here 思われます is the passive voice, which makes the subject of the whole sentence consistent. 人の in this context is like 他人の ("someone else's").

Answer (score 2):

Because of the rather antagonistic way you seem to be expressing your statement, I offer this:

> 人の年収を聞いて、（自分のを）ただ自慢したいだけでしょう？ You asking around other people's annual income, you simply want to boast (about your own) right?

And I can imagine you wanted to say this right to the person in question.